# Computing distinctions: speeding up an operation on all combinations of rows in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to compute the number of so-called distinctions from a given binary matrix G. Assuming the rows of G correspond to some individuals and its columns to some test cases, distinctions made by a test are defined as the number of pairs of individuals it differentiates.

I've come up with a very simple implementation:

```
distinctions = np.zeros(G.shape[1])
for p in itertools.combinations(np.arange(G.shape[0]), 2):
    distinctions += G[p[0], :] != G[p[1], :]
```

But it's to slow for my needs. I would be very grateful if you could help me speed up this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know the actual locations of the 1s and 0s, you just need to know how many of them there are.  For example, in the array

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

we see test 0 distinguishes nobody (0), test 1 can distinguish #0 and #1 from #2, for (2) * (1) total distinctions, test 2 can distinguish #1 from #0 and #2, for (1) * (2) total distinctions, and test 3 can distinguish #0 and #2 from #1, for (2) * (1) total distinctions, which gives us

```
[0, 2, 2, 2]
```

So really, we just need to count the number of 1s in a column and multiply that by the number of 0s in that column, because each 1 gives rise to (num_zeroes) distinctions.  IOW:

```
def slow(G):
    distinctions = np.zeros(G.shape[1])
    for p in itertools.combinations(np.arange(G.shape[0]), 2):
        distinctions += G[p[0], :] != G[p[1], :]
    return distinctions

def fast(G):
    ones = np.count_nonzero(G, axis=0)
    return ones * (G.shape[0] - ones)
```

which gives me

```
In [125]: G
Out[125]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [126]: slow(G)
Out[126]: array([6., 6., 4., 6., 6., 4., 6.])

In [127]: fast(G)
Out[127]: array([6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6])
```

and

```
In [130]: G = np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 1000))

In [131]: %timeit fast(G)
7.87 ms ± 344 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I haven't thought about the problem in this way. This is obviously a much better approach, thank you!